# ¿Cómo hacer que un filtro css aplique solamente al background y no a los elementos hijos?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una serie de imagenes que se muestran en escala de gris cuando el elemento tiene la clase `disabled` pero dicho filtro me está aplicando también a los elementos hijos por lo que el bloque completo me aparece en gris.

```css
.item {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.item.disabled {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.item .status {
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.item.disabled .status {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports)">
  <span class="status">ready</span>
</div>
<div class="item disabled" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports)">
  <span class="status">not ready</span>
</div>
```

¿Como hacer para que el texto que dice "not ready" me salga en rojo y no en gris?

Segun tengo entendido la propiedad css [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/filter) no es heredable y su valor inicial es `none` así que sólo debería aplicar al elemento sobre el que se encuentra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mi me había ocurrido esto hace tiempo, pero con el filter: blur, la solución esta en jugar con las posiciones de las cajas.

```css
.item {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.item.disabled {
  position: relative;
  
}
.item .status {
  background-color: green;
  bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.item.disabled .status {
  background-color: red;
}

.no-bw{
  top: 30px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  left:50%; 
  width: 76px;
  /*LA MITAD DEL ANCHO DE LA CAJA*/
  margin-left: -38px;
  }

.fondo-bw{
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="item" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports)">
  <span class="status">ready</span>
</div>
<div class="item disabled" style="">
    <div class="fondo-bw item" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports)"></div>
    <span class="no-bw">not ready</span>
</div>
```

Comment: aunque funciona esta bastante desprolijo y hay cosas que no hacen falta, para redondear la respuesta seria mejor dar un ejemplo minimalista. no hay necesidad de correr ;) saludos.

Comment: Parece que la solución al problema es no ponerle elementos hijos en primer lugar ya que el filtro siempre va a aplicar. Gracias por tu respuesta.